# How to run warbler (jruby on rails) on different port rather than 8080

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

I created a war file named `my_sample.war` and run `java -jar my_sample.war` . It runs at `port 8080` as default value. What do I do to change it to `port 3000`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass the port to the `java` invocation like so:

```
java -Dwarbler.port=3000 -jar my_sample.war
```

Alternatively, setting the environment variable `PORT` should work:

```
PORT=3000 java -jar my_sample.war
```